# Inserting image to a specific position in graph where points are scattered

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, graph, scatter-plot

I have generated image in Python where some figures are plotted on a graph where you can see both axis with ticks.

I want to insert on it a point cloud on  positions given by x_data, y_data.

However, when I use imgread and plt.scatter, the image is put not in the start of coordinates, not on (0,0). Another graph is drawn, image is somewhat in its middle.

I want to put this image to a top position so that (0,0) on image is the same as (0,0) on a graph that has point cloud. So points can be drawn on image exactly where they should be according to their coordinates.

So that (8,8) point will be exactly on (8,8) in the image graph. It currently is not.

Comment: matplotlib.pyplot.imread is normally used to read an image from a file (now PIL.Image.open is recommended for that). But if you produce your first graph with matplotlib.pyplot, you shouldn't have any difficulty with placing the second graph on the same axes. Could you please share your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is what you want the `origin="lower"` argument for `.imshow()`?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(34)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Data
xy = [(15, 3), (2, 7), (8, 12), (9, 4), (4, 10)]
image = np.random.rand(20, 20) * 0.5

# Plot
ax.imshow(image, origin="lower", cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax.scatter(*zip(*xy), color="lime")

# Annotate
for x, y in xy:
    ax.annotate(
        f"({x}, {y})",
        (x, y),
        xytext=(x + 1.2, y + 0.8),
        arrowprops={"color": "lime", "arrowstyle": "->"},
        color="lime",
        weight="bold",
    )

plt.show()
```

[image: imshow, scatter, annotate]